# How can I use design to teach history to 8th graders?

Tags: design-principles

I want to **use graphic design and website design to teach history** to 8th graders, so kids can express what they have learned about history and use their knowledge to teach others. I also want to use design practices to plan the research learning and analysis of the information.

I'm currently using wix.com as software, but what other resources are available to help me teach history to kids?

Comment: What is it exactly that you are looking for? Graphical work that will be used as web content to teach history? Please clarify.

Comment: @Yisela I Don't really get the question edit and removal of questions asking for clarification. You got a private email from Shane? You know exactly what Shane meant? Just curious.

Comment: The edit was based on the first edit and the comment Shane left to his own question 22 mins ago. The older comments were obsolete after those. I pasted them back in [the chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/graphic-design-corner) and we can re-add them if you feel they clarify things more.

Comment: Ahh okay. I was merely wondering. Since I missed the comment Shane made.

Comment: This sounds more like a question more about what web apps can be used in teaching than about design. You might get more answers at http://webapps.stackexchange.com/ especially on the functionality side of things (e.g. enabling kids to create and post things about a topic). I'd recommend posting there with a clear outline of the kind of things you want to enable the kids to do and issues you have with the things you've tried to show prior research.

Answer (score 4):

There's a book (and website) called *[D.I.Y. Kids](http://diykids.org/index.php)*. It's by Ellen and Julia Lupton. In this case D.I.Y. stands for "design-it-yourself." It contains a bunch of design project ideas for kids. It's a spinoff of another book called [*D.I.Y.: Design It Yourself*,](http://diykids.org/index.php) which is the same idea, but not necessarily aimed at kids. It might be an excellent resource for young students as well though.